# Leaflet custom image for empty tiles

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to use png image with 'no tiles' when there is no image(gray). I tried to use errorTileUrl but it does not work for me as a tile provider.

`tileservice.charts.noaa.gov/tiles/50000_1/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

does not return 404 or any error on empty tiles.

I can set it as

`document.querySelector(".leaflet-container").style.backgroundImage =  'url(http://boswellbros.co.uk/media/djcatalog2/images/item/5/rogers-victorian-tiles_l.png)'`

but on map pan it looks weird for me, as the background remains in place and the tiles move.

So is there a way to replace `empty/gray` tiles with my image?

Here is a fiddle for the above issue https://jsfiddle.net/dt61hv7x/1/

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#tilelayer-errortileurl